# Are there any crypography schemes which rely on Graph Isomorphism not being in P?

Tags: encryption

Are there any cryptography schemes having correctness relying on Graph Isomorphism not being in P?  If I should ask this question in the CS Theory area, I will migrate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Nope, not that I know of. GI is not a great problem from which to build primitives, because it's been known for several decades that many (most) classes of graphs have a poly-time algorithm for deciding isomorphism.

Comment: Interestingly, though, graph non-isomorphism is a standard example of an interactive zero-knowledge proof for a language not in NP. If GI collapses to P, I think GNI goes with it, so we'll need a new example in our crypto textbooks.

Comment: As I understand it, GI is collapsed to P: http://www.dharwadker.org/tevet/isomorphism/

Comment: @BrentKirkpatrick You may want to read http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32237/is-anyone-aware-of-a-counter-example-to-the-dharwadker-tevet-graph-isomorphism-a before putting faith in random papers on the internet :)

Comment: Indeed, the paper at http://www.dharwadker.org/tevet/isomorphism/ is not credible. However, Babai - a highly respected theoretical computer scientist - has shown that Graph Isomorphism is in *quasi*-polynomial time http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03547. This makes it very unsuitable for cryptographic applications (especially since the feeling is that it may very well be in $P$).

Comment: @Thomas Thank you.  I did not know that the Dharwadker and Tevet algorithm had made the rounds and been discussed.

Answer (score 5):

There is an elegant example of zero knowledge proof for graph isomorphism. The prover sends a randomly relabled graph and the verifier requests mapping to one of the originals. It is a very simple to understand and prove zero knowledge proof. However I don't believe anyone ever used this for authentication or such.
Obviously we now know graph isomorphism isn't hard after all making all these not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

We got a cryptographic algorithm and computer implementation
based on graph isomorphism.

An isomorphism between two graphs is a bijection between their vertices that pre
serves the edges.

For a graph $G$, let $M(G)$ denote the adjacency matrix of $G$.

Two graphs $G,H$ are isomorphic iff there exist permutation matrix $P$
such that $P M(G) P^{-1}=P M(G) P^T=M(H)$.

Observe that $P$ **need not be unique**.

Consider the following Diffie Hellman key exchange scheme based on
graph isomorphism.

Public parameters: graph $G$ of order $n$ with $A=M(G)$
and $n \times n$ permutation matrix $P_0$.

Alice chooses positive integer $X_A$ and set the private key the matrix
$privA=P_0^{X_A}$.
Alice make public her public key the matrix

$pubA=privA \cdot A \cdot privA^T=P_0^{X_A} A P_0^{-X_A}$.

Bob chooses positive integer $X_B$ and set the private key the matrix
$privB=P_0^{X_B}$.
Bob make public his public key the matrix $pubB=privB \cdot A \cdot privB^T$.

To compute shared secret, Allice computes
$M_1=privA \cdot pubB \cdot privA^T=P_0^{X_A+X_B} A P_0^{-X_A-X_B}$.

To compute shared secret, Bob computes
$M_2=privB \cdot pubA \cdot privB^T=P_0^{X_A+X_B} A P_0^{-X_A-X_B}$.

Since powers of permutation matrices commute, Allice and Bob know the shared
secret $M_1=M_2$.

The public keys $pubA,pubB$ are adjacency matrices of isomorphic graphs,
each of which is isomorphic to the public $G$.

Multiplicative discrete logarithm of permutation matrices is efficient
since the group order is $n$-smooth, but we believe to break
the algorithm adversary must solve $X A X^T=pubA$ for
permutation matrix $X$

> Q1 Is this algorithm at least as hard as graph isomorphism?

For permutation matrix $X$, the equation $X A X^T = pubA$
might have many solutions, which are isomorphism of the graph
$G$ to itself. For example take $G$ to be the complete graph
of order $n$. Then for all $X$, we have $X A X^T=pubA=A$.
This case is trivial since the shared secret is $A$.

When experimenting, we got $G=PaleyGraph(5)$ and $P_0$
such that we had $X A X^T=pubA$, but the shared secret was incorrect.

> Q2 are there choices of $G$, $P_0$ such the algorithm is harder
> than graph isomorphism?

Comment: Crossposted to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408757/diffie-hellman-cryptography-based-on-graph-isomorphism

Comment: This key exchange is insecure. The graph $M_{2}=(V_{2},E_{2})$ can be recovered since the edge sets $E_{2}\cap\{\{r,s\}\mid r\in R,s\in S\}$ can easily be produced by from the public information whenever $R,S$ are cycles in the permutation $P_{0}$.

Comment: On MO, I also posted an attack where a more general key exchange is broken using linear algebra.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/409594/22277 On MO, I have posted another attack that translates the problem of finding $X_{A}$ into a problem of solving a system of linear congruence equations.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no cryptographic scheme based on Graph isomorphism. The following is the key reasons.

The security of a cryptographic scheme largely depend on one-wayness of the underlying function. For a function to be [one-way](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function) it's not just need to be hard for few NP instances but must be hard for a random instance. In other words it is very easy to find problems that are hard for very instance but easy for majority of instances . Such problems may not come under P but they arn't one way functions either.
One such good example is the encryption scheme based on [subset-sum problem](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/lic13/lec05.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiQw_n6t7rSAhUFPI8KHfEzBOsQFggqMAM&usg=AFQjCNH4QFWhBIHPHhtzHTj-SMUIoDWFTQ&sig2=wgKec8DJlZBwfMCyhw3kSw), which was eventually broken due to the above specified reason.

Comment: The subset-sum problem can be thought of as a precursor to lattice cryptography.  See here for how subset some is treated as an NP-Complete problem: https://web.stevens.edu/algebraic/Files/SubsetSum/p229-lagarias.pdf